# PhpStorm Xdebug connected to client but not stopped

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

So weird issue started to appear on a new project for PhpStorm with Xdebug

Running PHP in Docker with all the same configurations as other projects, which Xdebug works for without problems, there's literally no difference between them after double-checking countless times, PhpStorm configurations are exactly the same.

Problem is everything looks to be ok, the connection appears but nothing is stopped, I've named this topic exactly same to which I found on here, spoilers ( it didn't help me :( )

Also enabled logging as suggested in that topic, this is the log for one session

```
[13] Log opened at 2020-08-12 15:50:53
[13] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.17.0.1:9000.
[13] I: Connected to client. :-)
[13] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/pub/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.20" protocol_version="1.0" appid="13" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.9.6"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[13] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[13] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[13] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[13] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[13] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[13] <- stdout -i 6 -c 1
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="6" success="1"></response>

[13] <- status -i 7
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="7" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[13] <- step_into -i 8
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="8" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/pub/index.php" lineno="13"></xdebug:message></response>

[13] <- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///var/ww/html/pub/index.php -n 13
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="130001"></response>

[13] <- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t line -f file:///var/ww/html/pub/index.php -n 27
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="130002"></response>

[13] <- stack_get -i 11
[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="11"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/html/pub/index.php" lineno="13"></stack></response>

[13] <- run -i 12
[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1Qb3dlcmVkLUJ5OiBQSFAvNy4zLjIw]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[U2V0LUNvb2tpZTogUEhQU0VTU0lEPTRkY2NiOTAzZjE2Yjg2YWVmNGQ1MjRjOTMxYTkzZDA3OyBleHBpcmVzPVdlZCwgMTItQXVnLTIwMjAgMTY6NTA6NTQgR01UOyBNYXgtQWdlPTM2MDA7IHBhdGg9LzsgZG9tYWluPWRldi5tYWdlbnRvOyBIdHRwT25seQ==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1NYWdlbnRvLUNhY2hlLUNvbnRyb2w6IG1heC1hZ2U9ODY0MDAsIHB1YmxpYywgcy1tYXhhZ2U9ODY0MDA=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1NYWdlbnRvLVRhZ3M6IGNhdF9jLGNhdF9jXzMsc3RvcmUsY21zX2IsY21zX3BfMixGUEM=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[UHJhZ21hOiBuby1jYWNoZQ==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Q2FjaGUtQ29udHJvbDogbWF4LWFnZT0wLCBtdXN0LXJldmFsaWRhdGUsIG5vLWNhY2hlLCBuby1zdG9yZQ==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[RXhwaXJlczogTW9uLCAxMiBBdWcgMjAxOSAxNTo0NjoyNiBHTVQ=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1NYWdlbnRvLUNhY2hlLURlYnVnOiBISVQ=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1Db250ZW50LVR5cGUtT3B0aW9uczogbm9zbmlmZg==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1YU1MtUHJvdGVjdGlvbjogMTsgbW9kZT1ibG9jaw==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[WC1GcmFtZS1PcHRpb25zOiBTQU1FT1JJR0lO]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Q29udGVudC1FbmNvZGluZzogZ3ppcA==]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[VmFyeTogQWNjZXB0LUVuY29kaW5n]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Q29udGVudC10eXBlOiB0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTg=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[DQo=]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[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]]></stream>

[13] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[AwAPLDcQs2QAAA==]]></stream>

[13] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="12" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[13] <- run -i 13
[13] Log closed at 2020-08-12 15:50:54
```

As seen here no indications of any error, help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows that the IDE is setting breakpoints on:

```
breakpoint_set -i 9 -t line -f file:///var/ww/html/pub/index.php -n 13
```

But the file that is being debugged is:

```
fileuri="file:///var/www/html/pub/index.php"
```

I think you just misspelled the path mappings in the IDE, where you used `/var/ww` instead of `/var/www`.

Comment: While this might solve the OP's problem it is of no value for people in the future because the problem was caused by a typo

Comment: Oh my god, I'm gonna lose my mind, thanks, feel so stupid now, i need a good sleep and more looking at www-s

Comment: @jrswgtr Maybe, but it teaches people to pay close attention to what's actually in the logs.